# Google Kubernetes logs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 545486 (python3) score 2016 or sacrifice child Killed process 545486 (python3) total-vm:579096kB, anon-rss:518892kB, file-rss:16952kB
```

This node logs and my container is continuously restarting randomly. Running python cotnainer with 4 replicas.

Python application contains socket with a flask. Docker image contain of `python3.5:slim`

```
Kubectl get nodes

NAME                                                 CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
gke-XXXXXXX-cluster-highmem-pool-gen2-f2743e02-msv2   682m         17%    11959Mi         89%
```

Today morning node log : `0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient cpu.`

But node CPU usage is 17% only

There not much running inside pod.

Comment: You've reserved your process too little memory.  Python needs a lot of memory - it appears that you've limited it to about 0.5GiB, and I'm not surprised that's not sufficient.  However, it's your responsibility to manage your memory consumption in the application as well.  If requested CPU is not available, nodes are unschedulable regardless of how much CPU is actually in use.  You seem fairly new to kubernetes - unless on a production cluster I recommend you remove mem and cpu limits and profile your app before reapplying them.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Hi Thankyou so much for writing back. Yes i am new to Kubernetes. i have restricted memory due to some time it's generate spike to 1.5GB per pod. so that after setting up a resource limit i am able to run 4 replicas of microservice.

Comment: any comment or suggestion: in kubernetes pod memory slowly increasing with time. we checked for memory leak but no traces so far.

Comment: if your ram usage spikes to 1.5 gigs, you have to accommodate that.  Run less instances or a bigger server, or write more memory efficient programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) and try to adjust resource requests and limits  for [CPU](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit) and [memory](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/#specify-a-memory-request-and-a-memory-limit). If your app starts hitting your CPU limits, Kubernetes starts throttling your container. Because there is no way to throttle memory usage, if a container goes past its memory limit it will be terminated (and restarted). So, using suitable limits should help you to solve your problem with restarts of your containers.

In case [request of your container exceeded limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#my-pods-are-pending-with-event-message-failedscheduling), Kubernetes will throw an error, similar to one you have, and won’t let you run the container.

After adjusting limits, you could use some monitoring system (like [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/)) to find the cause of potential memory leak.